# MariaDB10.4 - W10 machine, one slave + few regular standalone DBs - how to?

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, multi-database

I'm running a simple home/small business php/db server with Windows 10 and xampp with MariaDB.

I'd like to expand it to being it a DB slave for a "failover" PHP application hosted on another machine (if the main one fails, users can at least read-access the failover node). However, it should be hosted on the same PC where other - regular DBs for other apps/sites - are already running on XAMPP/MariaDB 10.4.27.

PHP is setup, master/slave are ready to be launched (used mariadb tutorial), however - mysqld_multi is NOT supported on Windows... any other way to achieve the desired result (regular standalone DB server + one slave for an external master on the same machine accessible for read-only operations)? Windows10 is a must...

I thought of making the whole computer a "slave" (following the replication tutorial by modifying my.ini), but I'm not sure how/if it will affect the regular DBs hosted there...

Thanks in advance.